# Sending text to text box using Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a script within Python using Selenium to open a social media page (Tumblr), input user login credentials, and make "quote" posts with a random sentence generator. I am able to input the credentials and select the create post icon using xpaths (driver.find_element_by_xpath) from the website, but when trying input text for the post with the xpath

```
//*[@id="redpop_iframePostForms"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p
```

using the

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="redpop_iframePostForms"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys("It worked!!")
```

I receive the error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id="redpop_iframePostForms"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]"}
```

I have tried using the other div classes within the list of divs, but I cannot find the correct one. I have also tried using the CSS selector with the code

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_seletor("div[@aria-label='Quote']").send_keys("It worked!!!")
```

but that provided the error

```
Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Any direction on where to go from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For no such element exception**

From your xpath, i can guess that element is present in an iframe. First switch to that frame and then find element you want to interact with.

**For invalid selector message**

General Syntax for locating element with css selector is :

```
tagname[attributeName=‘attributeValue’]
```

You don’t need to use @ with  attributeName. 
Also, you are fetching all the div elements present in the DOM with aria-label=‘Quote’ and sending keys which is not right. If you want to perform any action on elements, you need to put them in list and then iterate over it. Hope this helps.